# One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes or automatically add all missing attributes

Tags: android, xml

In Android Studio i'm getting a message One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes.And also suggestion is not showing while typing in xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity"> 

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello World!" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like you have to add `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes. Without your code, we can't say more than that.

Comment: @Geshode This is the code in XML
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Is that the only layout, which you use?

Comment: @Geshode Yes,this is the only layout in the activity and also when i type the code in xml it does not show suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Please add this library in your **build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Then try to create new layout, and add this in layout file

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

according to your requirement..

Comment: I tried all but shows same even when i set up a new project its shows same.

Answer (score 0):

I have Android studio 3.2 with built on September, 2018 and having same above issue. To fix this error, I have deleted cache files.

These are the followings steps you need to do:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Locate the path and Go to -> C:\Users\yourUserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches
3. Delete all the files inside the caches folder.
4. Open Android Studio.
5. You are done here!!.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Android Studio
- Locate the path and go to `C:\Users\yourUserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches`
- Delete all the files inside the caches folder
- Open Android Studio